# How to write such expression with for loop? particles[:, 2] %= 2 * np.pi python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, operation

How to write this expression `particles[:, 2] %= 2 * np.pi` using for loop?

Comment: What is the contents of ``particles`` inlcude that in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for iterations in particles:
    iterations[2] %= (2 * np.pi)
```